# Send SMTP Email through Exchange Server Using Zend_Mail - How to Diagnose these Errors

Tags: zend-framework, smtp, exchange-server, zend-mail

I have the following code:

```
$config = array(
   'auth' => 'login',
   'username' => 'domain\user',
   'password' => 'password',
   'ssl' => 'tls',
   'port' => 25,
);

$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('192.168.101.11',$config);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText($text);
$mail->setFrom('noreply@domain.com');
$mail->addTo($user->getEmail());
$mail->setSubject('Email subject');
$mail->send();
```

When I try to connect using what should be the correct credentials I get the following error in the log:

```
2010-10-12T13:00:59-07:00 ERR (3): AdminController::emailPassword - 5.7.1
2010-10-12T13:00:59-07:00 ERR (3): AdminController::emailPassword - #0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(261): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(250, 300)
        #1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(207): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->mail('noreply@domain...')
        #2 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
        #3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail.php(1178): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
...
```

When I try to connect and send an email using a definitely bad password I get the following error:

```
2010-10-12T13:03:52-07:00 ERR (3): AdminController::emailPassword - 5.7.3
2010-10-12T13:03:52-07:00 ERR (3): AdminController::emailPassword - #0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/Login.php(95): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(235)
#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
#2 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail.php(1178): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 /var/www/mreserve/application/controllers/AdminController.php(458): Zend_Mail->send()
...
```

My problem, I don't really know how to diagnose these errors. Where do I look up what 5.7.1 and 5.7.3 error codes are described, etc? Google wasn't helping me too much. When I plug in the credentials for my personal GMail account I am able to send mail just fine, so I know that I can send emails when configured correctly.

A few other possibly helpful tidbits, I am trying to send from a company Exchange that has created an email account for this user, I am trying to send to an email outside of the domain, and I don't have a lot of access to the exchange server- other than a few screenshots on how they set up their email clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are NDR (Non Delivery Report) codes for Exchange server.
[Here is a (rather old) blog entry describing them](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchangept/archive/2008/10/14/standard-ndr-codes-table-and-troubleshooting.aspx), and [another page listing the sames codes](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2007/exchange2007_ndr.htm) for exchange 2007.

### 5.7.1 Error code

"permission problem", which could point to a:

- a [SMTP relay problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_relay). Your account is not authorized to send emails to another domain.
- a sender/receiver problem. Your account is not authorized to send emails to a discussion list (because your account is not a member of it)
- other specific restrictions on your account.

IMHO, only the SMTP logs can tell the exact cause.

### 5.7.3 Error code

"sender prohibited" or "Not Authorized, security problem", depending on the source; could be consistent with wrong password submission.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the links. With those to guide me I was able to point the Exchange server admin in the right direction to fix the problem. I don't know what the ultimate solution was, however I do know that they had to fix it on their end and my code at least, wasn't at fault!

Comment: great! Lesson #1: always blame it on Exchange (just kidding)